# jquery if all text is visible in div

Tags: jquery, truncate

Im trying to write plugin truncating text to only one line, and give user ability to expand text, i tested lots of them but i dont find suitable for me , to slow, problems if jquery is not loaded etc.

I done this in following way
1. initial span
Very Long text 
w300 - means width 300

1. $('.trunc').oneLine();
2. plugin create >
    
   Very Long text 
   [+]

css 
.trunc {overflow:hidden  !important;  white-space:nowrap !important; display:inline-block;}

1. everything works ok 
   So i have only one line + i can expand

PROBLEM
i see expand sign[+] in every block, i want to see this only if text overflows block width I don't know how to determine if text is overflowing block. For example part of text is hidden.

Regards 
wicherqm

Comment: Can you do a character/length count comparison?  Or is that not accurate enough

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this what you're looking for?
http://jsfiddle.net/jjTcL/

fiddle code:

```
$(function() {
    var $d = $('<div/>');
    $('div').wrapInner($d);
    alert($('div div')[0].scrollWidth);
});
```